# ChromeOS recovery not permanent

Tags: google-chrome-os

I have a Samsung S3 enrolled in a domain.

One day it prompts with

```
Chrome OS is missing or damaged.
Please insert a recovery USB stick or SD card.
(note: the blue USB port will NOT work for recovery)
```

I've proceeded through [Google's recovery guide](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595) and the recovery will complete as expected. After working for a few hours or days it shuts down suddenly during use and starts up with the above error.

How can I recover this Chromebook so the recovery is permanent?

Comment: You might not be.   This sounds like the storage device is failing.  It shouldn't take days to recover the device.

Comment: It does not take days to recover. The recovery *lasts* for a few days before reverting to the "Chrome OS is missing or damaged" error

Comment: Clarify your question by making a modification to your question because your current statement is not clear.  Furthermore I statement still stands, if you keep getting this error, that indicates a storage device failure.

Comment: I am also confused as to what the S3 has to do with the Chromebook recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact [Google Chromebook support](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1280301?hl=en) . Sounds defective. And Btw what does the phone have to do with it?

I particularly like the [Chrome Ninjas](https://support.google.com/chromebook/troubleshooter/1342028) Option